# How to avoid firebase only showing welcome screen

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I just started using firebase(the first project actually). I've been trying for days to get my website running, however, whenever 'firebase deploy', it always goes to the welcome screen. Meaning I only see "Firebase hosting setup is complete". Why is this? I have tried the fixes I saw online, such as "dist/app name" and even edited stuff in the firebase.json file. Nothing works, I don't know how to see my website when I click the given URL, for some reason it doesn't work. Help would be much appreciated!!! Thank You, guys!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it's refered in the Step 2 of [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-fix-firebase-hosting-showing-welcome-screen-instead-index-html-page/) the reason behind the welcome screen, **is because the index.html has modified itself when you selected "Y" while initializing the Firebase.**

It has basically replaced your own index file with this one. Check and replace the index file and next time, do not overwrite index.html file.